# Web Services hosted over EC2 instance does not accessed sometimes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have hosted some Web Services on my EC2 instance and it was working fine. Now from few days, suddenly web services does not work sometime.
When i try to call the web services via rest client, it says "The requested URL can't be reached." (sometimes) and most of the time it works as expected.
I'm sure it not related with code or deployment side as it used to work most of time but gives above error sometimes.

[image]
[image]
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If it works sometimes but not always, then at least you know that you have the right network/security configuration. If your DNS name only resolves to one IP address, then that configuration is okay too. It sounds like the EC2 instance is not always responding. You should consult the logs on the EC2 instance to discover more. (Presumably, your application logs and whatever is serving traffic on port 80.)

Comment: how to check logs in free tier EC2?

Comment: The AWS Free Tier is a billing discount. It does not impact the way services are implemented. Did you create the enrich app on an EC2 instance? Or Elastic Beanstalk? It's your application, so hopefully you'd know where to find the logs.

Comment: Yeah, I created on EC2 instance only, but where should i check logs on the instance?

Comment: What did you install on the server? What is _receiving_ the API request?

Comment: services are hosted on IIS.

Comment: Then you should check the IIS logs to see whether the requests are being received and whether your code that responds to the API request is generating an error. Either the request never made it to the code, or the code failed (or, possibly, something else). The logs should give you insight to figure out which is the case.